# Need help setting up parsing from a text document. Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

This is a sample code. You need to get the url from the request with txt

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15;rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",}

page = requests.get('https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=test', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').find_all("a", class_="result__url", href=True)

for link in soup:
print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Need help setting up parsing from a text document

Comment: isn't 'html.parser'? Can you edit your question and format the code accordingly?

Comment: This should be a parser on Python. The essence of the project itself to issue me search sites with a test document for analysis. Now he will make the result specifically from the request. Need help for the keywords Python took from the text of the document. Just learning and I can not do anything.

Comment: What information do you want to get?  If you do that request in a browser, you can look at the HTML it returned.  From that, you should be able to figure out how to find the information you want.  We can't advise you on that.

Comment: I need a string from a text document to be sent to the search

Comment: Do you mean instead of "test" you want to send a string variable?

Comment: Yes, I need to set up an alternate otpak with txt in the test place

Answer (score 0):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

```
search_text = "foo"
page = requests.get(f'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q={search_text}', headers=headers).text
```

Comment: I need to have multiple keywords. Which I can write to txt one by one.

Comment: you mean `https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=foo,bar,baz` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, argparse, ScrapeSearchEngine, time, threading
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
}
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dorks", help="Your dorks list", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
with open(args.dorks, 'r') as f:
    dorks = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]

scraped = 0
for dork in dorks:
    if os.name == "nt":
        os.system('title SQLI Crawler ^| Dork: '+str(dork)+' ^| Scraped Links: '+str(scraped))
search = (dork)
page = requests.get(f'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q={search_text}', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').find_all("a", class_="result__url", href=True)

for link in soup:
    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: I can't understand my mistake in this

Comment: It's hard for me to explain )

Comment: I also don’t understand how to set up an unlimited number and go to the next page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Added new changes. I can't add the number of pages in search and save to links.txt

```
import os, requests, argparse, colorama, ScrapeSearchEngine, time, threading
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
}
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dorks", help="Your dorks list", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
with open(args.dorks, 'r') as f:
    dorks = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]

scraped = 0
for dork in dorks:
    if os.name == "nt":
        os.system('title SQLI Crawler ^| Dork: '+str(dork)+' ^| Scraped Links: '+str(scraped))
search = (dork)
page = requests.get(f'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q={search}', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').find_all("a", class_="result__url", href=True)
for link in ScrapedLinks:
            scraped += 1
            open('links.txt', 'a+').write(link+"\n")

            print(f"[{Fore.CYAN}{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}{Fore.RESET}] [{Fore.YELLOW}INFO{Fore.RESET}] "+link)

            if args.scan == 'true':
                threading.Thread(target=scanner, args=(link, )).start()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).